# Ember list of checkbox on check one send rest

Tags: ember.js, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes in my template:

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th></th>
                        <th>Sender</th>
                        <th>Title</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    {{#each message in model.entities}}

                        <tr>

                            <td class="cell-star">
                                {{input type="checkbox" name=message.id tabindex=message.id class="starBox" checked=message.isStar }}

                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-broadcaster">
                                {{message.notification.autor.firstName}} {{message.notification.autor.lastName}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-title">
                                {{#link-to 'notifications.details' message.notification.id}}{{message.notification.title}}{{/link-to}} {{#unless message.isRead}} (new) {{/unless}}
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    {{/each}}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And now i want to send rest query every time when i change some of the checkbox state with id of changed checkbox.
What should i write in my controller?

i have tried something like that but i cannot get data of changed checkbox:

```
updateStarStatus: function() {

   console.log('checkbox clicked');
//here should be something like that:
//$.getJSON(apiHost + "/api/forum/star/"+id);

}.observes('model.entities.@each.isStar'),
```

im not using emberData. My model looks like this:

```
model: function() {
          return  $.getJSON(apiHost + "/api/forum");

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the observesBefore method to track the changes and make a diff in the observes method, but I'd rather use the native on change event, to trigger an action and pass the object:

```
<div {{action "updateStarStatus" message on="change"}}>
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=message.isStar}}
```

and in the controller

```
actions: {
    updateStarStatus: function(message) {
      alert(message.id)
    }
  }
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zohaqodese/2/

Comment: Thanks. I didn realise i can track checkbox change by parent div. One problem with this script is that i have to check every changed checkboxes not jus one i pressed but i can live with it ;)

Comment: Well i dont know why but it doesnt work. I paste your code without any changes. if i find why i post it here.

Comment: Ok one change and it works. Action updateStarStatus must be in router not controller. Thanks again :)`